# valid element is not highlighted when user clicks the submit button

Tags: javascript, html, twitter-bootstrap-3, jquery-validation-engine

I am currently using jQuery validation plugin to validate my form fields. I've set a rule where the **username** field is **not required**, the **account name** field is **required** and the **comments textarea** field is **not required.** When user **clicks** the "save" button, the **'has-error'** class will highlight the invalid element. However, the **'has-success'** class did not highlight the textarea valid element. Why is that so? Here is a screenshot of my **problem**, the **desired** result as well as my **codes**

**Error picture, textarea not highlighted**
[image: Error picture, textarea not highlighted]

**Desired result**
[image: Desired result]

```js
 $(document).ready(function () {
        $.validator.setDefaults({

            errorClass: 'help-block',


            highlight: function (element) {
                $(element)
                    .closest('.form-group')
                    .addClass('has-error');

            },

            unhighlight: function (element) {
                $(element)
                    .closest('.form-group')
                    .removeClass('has-error')
                    .addClass('has-success');
            }
        });

        $('#dataForm').validate({
            rules: {
                userNameInput: {
                    required: false
                },
                accountNameInput: {
                    required: true
                },
                commentInput: {
                    required: false
                }
            }
        });

    });

    $('#saveButton').on('click', function () {

        if ($('#dataForm').valid() == true) {

        }

        alert('nice');
    });
```

```html
<form id="dataForm" method="post" action="#">
    <div class="form-group col-md-12">
        <label class="control-label col-md-4" for="accountNameInput">Account name</label>
        <input type="text" id="accountNameInput" name="accountNameInput" class="form-control font-bold"
               maxlength="100" placeholder="Account name" value="" />
    </div>

    <div class="form-group col-md-12">
        <label class="control-label  col-md-4" for="userNameInput">userName</label>
        <input type="text" id="userNameInput" name="userNameInput" class="form-control font-bold"
               maxlength="100" placeholder="userName" value="" />
    </div>

    <div class="form-group col-md-12">
        <label class="control-label col-md-4" for="commentInput">Comments</label>
        <textarea class="form-control" id="commentInput" rows="5"></textarea>
    </div>

    <input type="button" class="btn btn-primary" value="Save" id="saveButton" />

</form>
```

Comment: First of all, how can we help you if we can't replicate the problem with the code you provided. Second, you say that the textarea is NOT required but in the code you have `commentInput: {
                    required: true
                }`

Comment: unhighlight only adds the class if the field has errored and then is successful, you probably want to use `validClass` - https://jqueryvalidation.org/validate/#validclass-1

Comment: Hi @MihaiT That was a typo mistake, I changed to required: false, still does not work

Comment: Check @Pete 's comment. And also one more question, does the textarea receive the `has-success` class?